# Javascript Canvas Alpha not working on Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, canvas

I am attempting to draw a circle with a radial gradient on a canvas and apply an alpha to it. It works well on chrome, however it does not seem to work on firefox. Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1m4wbdgc/

Here is the code:

```
context.globalAlpha = 0.2;
var gradient = context.createRadialGradient(x, y, radius / 2, x, y,
            radius);
gradient.addColorStop(0, '#525455');
gradient.addColorStop(1, '#202d33');
context.beginPath();
context.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
context.closePath();
context.fillStyle = gradient;
context.fill();
```

Why is the alpha not working on firefox?

Here is a screenshot from Firefox:
[image]

As you can see, the alpha is not working correctly.
My Firefox version is: 41.0.2

Comment: Could you be more specific as to what is not working? I see the same gradient on a circle on both chrome and firefox. Side note, at first I thought it was just a black box, maybe for sake of example you could change the colors to something more visible. FYI, tested on firefox v.42.0 and shows the same results as chrome v.46.0.2490.80

Comment: "Why is the alpha not working on firefox?" - The alpha channel is not working on firefox.

Comment: Sorry, if it is of any help at all, I can't replicate the issue, the alpha works fine on firefox v.42.0. Tested with different alpha values and it works as expected.

Comment: I added a screenshot and my firefox version. I am going to update my browser, still I am curious what could be causing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using FF Developer Edition 43.0a2
Well quite surprised at this behaviour, definitely not in the spec. After some hunting it turns out to be a bug in firefox. [Bug 1164912](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1164912). dated 15th, May 2015 so been around for a while.

There is a simple work around by setting the colour stops with CSS rgba function and multiplying the alpha by the global alpha `rgba(R,G,B,alpha * ctx.globalAlpha)` I tried that on the fiddle supplied and it worked perfectly on FF.

You will have to use that method until they fix it.

Comment: uh? I think it only concerns windows machines then... still can't repro even with the code provided in bug report